# nil test on interface fails

Tags: go, error-handling, null

Can someone explain this go code to me?
When this is invoked, the `err != nil` returns true, thus leading to a nil pointer reference.

```
type E struct{}

func (e E) Error() string {
    return ""
}

func DoStuff() *E {
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var err *E
    err = DoStuff()
    log.Println(err) // nil
    testErr(err)
}

func testErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("got error", err.Error())
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/iys7U_UMhG

I have understood that this has something to do with the fact that I am dealing with a nil-struct-pointer casted to an interface...

However I am confused how to design this interface `DoStuff`, if one wants to return a "smart" error object, not just plain `error`.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track. Thing is that you are returning pointer to struct and your `Error` method is implemented with non-pointer caller.

Following should work (I only added `*` for receiver of `Error` method:

```
package main

import "log"

type E struct{}

func (e *E) Error() string {
    return ""
}

func DoStuff() *E {
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var err *E
    err = DoStuff()
    log.Println(err) // nil
    testErr(err)
}

func testErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("got error", err.Error())
    }
}
```

Comment: While this does not crash, it still echoes "got error" -- even though the error value passed is actually nil?